# Why the Software Updater asked for password only in the first attemp of installing updates?

Tags: updates, password, update-manager

Sometimes, the Software Updater asks for a password (normally when you try to install kernel updates).

Every time that I connect to the Internet, the first thing I do is check for updates. And I got 2 updates today.

When I tried to install them, I was asked for the password to install, but I thought it was strange, since it wasn't a kernel update, so I clicked in the cancel button and the update was canceled.

So, I ran again the Software Updater and I got the same programs update, but after pressing to install, it didn't asked for a password and it installed the updates.

So, the question is: Why it only asked in the first time? Is this a bug or anything? Should I be worried about that?

Thank you guys for helping me.

EDIT: I haven't noticed anything strange on syslog and auth.log.

Answer (score 1):

When an update is only updating existing packages, you won't be prompted for your password.

However, when new packages are required, such as when there is a change in dependencies for an installed package or a new kernel version, then you are asked to provide a password.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But still, It asked for the password only in the first time (I canceled the update because it asked for the password, but I tried to update it again, and in the second time it didn't asked for it and installed the updates). Do you know if this is normal?

Comment: Yes, password is asked once per 15 minutes if entered succesfully.

Comment: @Rinzwind Sorry, but i think you didn't understand my question. What happenned is that I didn't put my password in the first attempt of update, and it didn't even asked for it in the second attempt. Then, is this a bug? Should I be worried about that?